# pythonic way to initialize instance variables

Tags: python, initialization

which of the two are more pythonic?

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.v1 = None
        self.v2 = None
        self.v3 = None
        self.foo()

    def foo(self):
        self.v1, self.v2, self.v3 = ...
```

or:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.v1, self.v2, self.v3 = self.foo()

    def foo(self):
        return ...
```

What I infer myself is that in the first example it is not clear at first glance what `self.foo()` does, until someone reads through the method itself.

But the problem with the second one is that it may arise the warning that: `foo` method may be static.

Comment: wouldn't you want to be able to pass arguments to your constructor and only set the non-specified args to the default? i.e. `def __init__(self, v1=None, v2=None, v3=None):` and then be able to call `a = A(v2=some_value)` and have `__init__` set the values for `v1` and `v2`?

Comment: Potential approach #3: don't create any attributes of self in the `__init__`, instead creating them directly within `foo`. There's no rule that says that attributes need to be declared within init before they can be defined somewhere else, or anything.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist actually no. in my code, I just need a path as an input, and many variables are initialized according to that path.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to initialize a class is:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, arg1=None, arg2=None):
        self.arg1=arg1
        self.arg2=arg2
```

Since you want to initialize variables using a file, you may want to use ConfigParser. ConfigParser allows you to read from a file and access key-value pairs easily.

```
from configparser import ConfigParser
config = ConfigParser()
config.read('example.conf')

class A:
    def __init__(self, config):
        self.arg1=config['arg1']
        self.arg2=config['arg2']
```

My example class above takes in a config object in which you can get the values you stored from a file.

P.S. I didn't test the code above. Take a look at [the configparser docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but in my case the variables are calculated with respect to images in the directory, and they are not constant to be put in config file.